# Pausing Video using GPUImage framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage, video-recording

I have been trying to implement "Pause/Resume" option in one of GPUImage project examples "SimpleVideoFilter" and so far, its going good except the issue of "pausing" video. I'm using the below mentioned code to pause video

```
- (void)pauseCameraCapture;
{
    capturePaused = YES; }

- (void)resumeCameraCapture;
{
    capturePaused = NO; }
```

The issue is that the video gets stuck on the last frame and the "pause" duration also gets in total video duration,..

so for example, if i record for 5sec and pause it for 10sec and resume recording again for 5sec, that SHOULD be 10sec of total recording HOWEVER, when i play the video, it plays for 5sec and then gets stuck on the last frame for next 10sec "pause time" and then plays again the last 5sec..

What i want is simple, if i record for 5sec and pause it for 10sec and resume recording again for 5sec, it should only record 10min of recording in total.

I searched this issue but couldn't find anything that solves this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i know the question is old but i was working on similar task and found a nice solution using GPUImage. I found this [project forked from GPUimage](https://github.com/evfemist/GPUImage) . Here movieWriter class has been changed in a way that video can be paused in excat way as described in question.

All you need to do is set `movieWriter.paused=YES` when you pause the video and set `movieWriter.paused=NO` when you resume the video recording . Where movieWriter is object of class   **GPUImageMovieWriter**

Worked perfectly for me .Hope this will help someone in future.

Comment: Beautiful, helped me so much.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `[videoCamera pauseCameraCapture];` on your GPUImageVideoCamera to stop the flow of frame buffers from the camera, and then also call `[movieWriter finishRecording];` on your GPUImageMovieWriter to complete the first clip.

Then when you finally restart the video camera with a call to `[videoCamera resumeCameraCapture];` you'll want to make sure you are writing to a fresh URL in your movieWriter.

Later you stitch together the individual clips you've created with your favorite techniques from the AVFoundation toolbag, and save your completed work.

I'm making some assumptions about what you are doing because you didn't post very much code, so I have to guess about what you're doing a bit. More specifics in your question help...